# Fill blank cells with cell values below

Tags: excel, vba

I code to fill down values. This is straight forward and can be done even without a script. (special - blanks - =value - ctrl entr)

I have another column where I need to copy the data upwards.

As seen in the image below, column A is filled downwards using the code;

```
Sub FillDown()
With Range("A:A")
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
.Value = .Value
End With
End Sub
```

Operations Period is column A. Occurences are column Q. They are not all 1s. There are mixed values.

Column Q has the data which needs to be filled upward.

[image: Column Q values to be copied to the above blank cells.]

[image: Column Q desired result]

Comment: Are you trying to fill the blanks with 1s? Not sure which is col Q and A ?

Comment: My apologies, i snipped the column name out.
Operations Perios is column A.
Occurences are column Q.
They are not all 1s. There are mixed values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted for going backwards. Not sure there is a cleverer way to do this. Over my head if there is.

```
Sub FillDown()

Dim r As Range

For Each r In Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Areas
    r.Value = r.Offset(r.Rows.Count).Resize(1).Value
Next r

End Sub
```

---

Before

[image]

---

After

[image]